# Proper Maven POM etiquette

Tags: java, maven

We are suffering under a hugely complex build process for our flagship web application.   We have a Maven POM file that includes the following:

- Two complete web server installations
- A complete (and enormous) JavaScript library build (invoking a completely separate Ant build)
- A complete download   and installation of a database engine
- Settings to build several different "flavors" of the application
- Settings to run unit tests, Selenium tests, both or neither

The downside of all this is that when something blows up, it can take hours or days to find the problem.

Are there any formal or informal guidelines that say what should or shouldn't be included in a Maven POM?  Or is it just "if you can fit it in, jam it in there?"

Comment: Consider this:  With your project properly modularized, what can you start moving into their own separate repositories?

Comment: What if the project's not modularized?  What if it's a giant spaghetti monster?

Comment: The only way to fix a giant spaghetti monster is one bite at a time.  Find one part that you can pull into a separate module.  Move its code and related Maven plugins into a separate project.  Add an aggregator POM to get the whole build working again.  Then, pull off another part into a separate module.  Rinse and repeat.  It might seem overwhelming, but if you don't start, it won't get better.

Comment: The only answer to this is modularize your build which means modularize your application. No relationship to Maven.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not directly related to Maven. You should base your build process on well established guidelines. You can start by reading [Implementing build and release best practices with Rational Build Forge software.](ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/software/rational/web/whitepapers/RAW14005-USEN-00.pdf) They define 10 good practices

> - Practice one: develop a build management strategy
> - Practice two: establish complete reproducibility
> - Practice three: automate processes and integrate essential systems
> - Practice four: institute centralized access and collaboration for all stakeholders
> - Practice five: link build proceses to deployment environments
> - Practice six: use metrics to evaluate progress and performance
> - Practice seven: apply build acceleration techniques
> - Practice eight: abstract processes and metadata from
>     physical resources
> - Practice nine: optimize processes and supporting
>     architecture design
> - Practice ten: build early and often

Even if Maven is not used in this document this can gives you an idea of what to do.